# SQL- How would I display a result for each account # start with 3s (Eg 300,301, 302..) in a NOT EXIST statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a correlated sub query SQL statement:

```
 SELECT AccountNo, AccountDescription
 FROM [AP].[dbo].GLAccounts AS Inv_Main
 WHERE NOT EXISTS   
     (Select *
    FROM [AP].[dbo].Vendors AS Inv_Sub
    WHERE Inv_Main.AccountNo = Inv_Sub.DefaultAccountNo)
 ORDER BY AccountNo;
```

How would I display a result for each account # start with 3s (Eg 300,301, 302..) How would I do that? Do I add a between...and... clause?

Comment: How account numbers stored? it's integer or some character type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add it as part of the WHERE clause.

```
 SELECT 
 AccountNo, 
 AccountDescription
 FROM [AP].[dbo].GLAccounts AS Inv_Main
 WHERE 
 (
     NOT EXISTS   
     (
         Select *
         FROM [AP].[dbo].Vendors AS Inv_Sub
         WHERE 
         (Inv_Main.AccountNo = Inv_Sub.DefaultAccountNo) AND
         (Inv_Main.AccountNo BETWEEN 299 AND 400)
     ) 
 ) 
 ORDER BY AccountNo;
```

Comment: Would it work if we used a between clause in a NOT EXIST statement?

Comment: @LisaTse Yes it would.